# SPRING Boot App Integration with IdP/PING Federate

Tags: spring-boot, single-sign-on, ping, pingfederate, idp

I'm new here and posting the first question ever, and coming straight to the point.

I have a N Tier Application, Front UI on AngularJS, backend on Spring Boot and a NoSQL DB with some caching attached to it.

I'm struggling in getting the SSO configured using PING Identity for my Home grown application for following reason.

1. Lack of knowledge on PING SSO.
2. The knowledge that i have gained so far only gives me limited visibility on how i can achieve the solution for having a successful SSO configured.

Summarized Solution:

Front End UI  -- Speaks to Middleware Service for Auth(current design) -- Middleware Service acts as a Interceptor for my backend services(also known as BFF) which handles all my tokens for necessary handshaking. --- Backend Services performs logics & functions

Problem: Trying to bring in PING for SSO is confusing:
as far as i know PING can be configured in 2 ways.

1. OAUTH2.0
2. SAML Based Auth.

in Oauth, User would access, Ping URL with context path which will internally speak to PING federate and AD and return a Token.. i might be wrong here. hence need clarification! as im not an expert on PING.
the confusion in case of OAUTH is, its totally confusing.. i have used oauth before, but via PING using it for the first time.

in SAML based Auth, again a PING URL with context path which will internally perform its work and then add some Assertion and then return the SAML token to a POST endpoint.
the confusion in case of SAML is as following:
if i configure my middleware to receive the SAML Token, how can i redirect the user to welcome page?

PS the middleware has some encryption logic that cannot be by passed!

any help in this matter would be highly appreciated. as im looking to see what options do i have on PING or even on my Springboot app.

Comment: This is a poorly worded question, because I can't figure out what you are asking for. Are you asking for guidance on choosing between OAuth and SAML? Are you asking for guidance on configuring OAuth (or SAML) on PingFederate? What "middleware" are you using? What are your application requirements from an authentication and token validation and lifetime requirements?